# HTML5 file api and octokit.js and binary file

Tags: javascript, html, git, blob, html5-filesystem

I try to make form which can upload binary data via octokit.js to the github. For example some pdf or image (binary blob). My problem is that all my attempts ends with damaged data at the github side.

Minimal working example: http://jsfiddle.net/keddie/7r3f4q77/

```js
var _arrayBufferToBase64 = function (buffer) {
  var binary = '';
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  var len = bytes.byteLength;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return window.btoa(binary);
};

var go = function () {
var config = {
    user: $('#user').val(),
    repo: $('#repo').val(),
    token: $('#token').val(),
    handler: document.getElementById('file').files[0]
};

var reader = new FileReader();
var github = new Octokit({
    token: config.token
});
var repo = github.getRepo(config.user, config.repo);
var branch = repo.getBranch();

reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    var files = {};
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {

        /* Anothers attempts:
        files[ 'x1.pdf' ] = {
            isBase64: true,
            content: evt.target.result
        };
        files[ 'x2.pdf' ] = {
            isBase64: true,
            content: evt.target.result.substring('data:application/octet-stream;base64,'.length)
        };
        */
        files['x4.pdf'] = {
            isBinary: true,
            isBase64: true,
            content: _arrayBufferToBase64(evt.target.result)
        };
    } else {
        console.warn(evt.target.error);
    }
    branch.writeMany(files, "API test commit 1").then(function (res) {
        if (res) {
            console.log('ok');
            $('#result').text('OK');
        } else {
            console.error(res);
            $('#result').text('Error');
        }
    });
 };
 var blob = config.handler.slice(0, config.handler.size);
 //reader.readAsDataURL(blob);   
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#submit').click(go);
});
```

And HTML:

```
<p>User:
 <input type="text" id="user" />
</p>
<p>Repo:
 <input type="text" id="repo" />
</p>
<p>Token:
 <input type="text" id="token" />
</p>
<p>File:
 <input type="file" id="file" />
</p>
<p>
 <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

My second problem is how to find filename in reader.onloadend callback (but this is minor issue).

Relevant is this issue: https://github.com/philschatz/octokit.js/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in octokit.js library.

I prepare pull request: https://github.com/philschatz/octokit.js/pull/72